# Where can I find documentation or projects related to Clustered Z-score Least Square Support Vector Method?

Tags: python, clustering, least-squares, svm, z-score

I have read about CZLSSVM (Clustered Z-score Least Square Support Vector Method) being better than kNN for missing value imputation but could not find projects on this method. Do you guys have something related to CZLSSVM?